# how to alert a message when click on the second level on fancytree.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I'm using fancytree.js i want to alert a message when i clic on a node. but not all nodes. Just when clicking on the nodes in the 2nd level. Example

```html
 <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
        </ul>
 
        <li>2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
        </ul>
   
        <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

i want just alert when on clicking on 1.1 and 1.2 or 2.1 and 2.2

```
$(document) . ready(function () {
    var data = '{{ path('gouvernorat_map') }}';
    $("#filter_switches") . fancytree({
        source: {
            url:data
        },
        icon: false,
        keyboard: true,
        quicksearch: false,
        tooltip: false,
        click: function (event, data) {
            alert(data . node + '---' + data . node . key + '---' + data . node . title + '---');
        }
    });
});
```

> this alert when i click in any level. so how can i did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can ask the level from any node by using `data.node.getLevel()`. If you put this into an if-statement, you can filter by level.

For more information, see [the documentation of fancytree](http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html#getLevel)

Good luck